# Find the number of spanning trees of a dumbbell graph.

Tags: graph-theory

A (k, l)-dumbbell graph is obtained by taking a complete graph on k
(labeled) nodes and a complete graph on l (labeled) nodes, and connecting them
by a single edge. Find the number of spanning trees of a dumbbell graph.

Do I have use Kruskal's algorithm for this problem? I am not sure where to begin.

Answer (score 2):

**Hints**

- There is one edge of your graph which must be included in any spanning tree.
- The number of spanning trees in a complete graph is known, see https://oeis.org/A000272

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1:**
The number of spanning trees in a complete graph $K_n$ of order $n$ is $n^{n -2}$ according to [Cayley's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_formula).

**Hint 2:**

> Knowing the number of trees spanning each of the two maximal cliques (maximal complete subgraphs) of the dumbbell graph, use the [fundamental counting principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) to find the number of trees spanning the full dumbbell graph.

**Hint 3:**

> Let $n$-dumbbell denote the dumbbell graph created by joining by means of a bridge edge two complete graphs $K_n$. Then, for $n \in [3, 4, 5, 6, \ldots]$ the number of spanning trees is 9, 256, 15625, 1679616, $\ldots$, respectively.

**Full solution:**

> Any trees spanning the full graph will have to use the bridge edge. Thus, each of the $n^{n -2}$ trees spanning one of the maximal cliques can be connected to each of the $n^{n -2}$ trees spanning the other maximal clique by using the bridge edge. Using the fundamental counting principle, we have that the total number of spanning trees of a dumbbell graph of order $n$ is $n^{n -2} \cdot n^{n -2} = (n^{n -2})^2$.